# Is the cartesian product of objects in an elementary topos cancellative?

Tags: topos-theory

My question is the internalization of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293363/is-cancellation-of-cartesian-product-possible-i-think-so-but-am-having-trouble) to an elementary topos $C$.

Is it true that: For objects $X,Y$ and $Z$ in an elementary topos $C$ with $X\times Y\cong X\times Z$, then also $Y\cong Z$?

Comment: Your question has very little to do with that question. Equality is a much stronger condition than isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the elementary topos $\mathsf{Set}$, where we assume the axiom of countable choice. If $X$ and $Y$ are countably infinite sets, and $Z$ is a finite non-empty set, then $X\times Y\cong X\times Z$ but $Y\not\cong Z$.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Zev's nontrivial counterexample, there is the following trivial one: Consider the case $X = \emptyset$ (initial object). Then $X \times Y$ and $X \times Z$ are initial as well (because in a topos, the initial object is [strict](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+initial+object) and we have the projection morphisms) and thus always isomorphic, irrespective of $Y$ and $Z$.